# MySQL throwing error "Statement is incomplete expecting if" when trying to create procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have been trying to create a procedure in MySQL but it throws this error whenever I try to run it even though I have specified a delimiter.I'm new to MySQL so I don't know what I'm doing wrong . None of the other questions seem to have my problem

```
delimiter //

create procedure get_count(in com varchar(20))
begin  

  if(com='gre') then
    select count(*) as "No of Employees" from jobs where min_salary > 10000;
  else if(com='eq') then
    select count(*) as "No of Employees" from jobs where min_salary = 10000;
  else if(com='less') then
    select count(*) as "No of Employees" from jobs where min_salary < 10000;
  else
    select ("Invalid");
  end if; 
end //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: rtm elseif not else if.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html

Comment: @P.Salmon any reason you're not posting that as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

MySql procedure's if-else ladder correct syntax:

```
IF expression THEN
   statements;
ELSEIF elseif-expression THEN
   elseif-statements;
… … … …
ELSE
  else-statements;
END IF;
```

you need to correct `else if` to `elseif`

Answer (score 2):

As P.Salmon said Elseif and not else if

```
delimiter //

create procedure get_count(in com varchar(20))
BEGIN  

  IF (com='gre') THEN
    SELECT COUNT(*) as "No of Employees" FROM jobs WHERE min_salary > 10000;
  ELSEIF (com='eq') then
    SELECT COUNT(*) as "No of Employees" FROM jobs WHERE min_salary = 10000;
  ELSEIF (com='less') then
    SELECT count(*) as "No of Employees" FROM jobs WHERE min_salary < 10000;
  ELSE
    select ("Invalid");
  END IF; 
END // 
delimiter ;
```